# Why wouldn’t mongoDB update the “Date” field of my user entry?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I created a User schema in my React App as follows:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
{
profileId: String,
expirationDate: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
credits: { type: Number, default: 0 },
},
{ timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at" } }
);
```

When the user pays me, I want to reset/update two fields: the expirationDate and credits via a post method. Here’s the code I use on my expressjs backend server to update the database entry on MongoDB Atlas:

```
req.user.expirationDate = new Date(
req.user.expirationDate.setDate(req.user.expirationDate.getDate() + 30)
);
req.user.credits += 1;
const user = await req.user.save();

res.send(user);
```

Once the operation succeeded, I can see the field of “credits” gets updated (increased by 1). However, the “expirationDate” field remains unchanged. What’s more curious is that when I send the updated user object to my frontend server with “res.send(user)”, I can see the updated expirationDate in the console.

[Successfully updated user model as designed/intended: seen from frontend console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar1OD.png)

But below is what I saw in my mongoDB:

[Updated user entry in MongoDB: the Date field "expirationDate" is not updated; but, the "credits" field is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9elM8.png)

What is going on here? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue recently and haven't figured out the actual reason behind this, but as a workaround try telling mongoose explicitly that the `expirationDate`-field was changed:

```
req.user.expirationDate = new Date(
    req.user.expirationDate.setDate(req.user.expirationDate.getDate() + 30)
);
req.user.markModified('expirationDate');
await req.user.save();
```

EDIT:

Just debugged it again and I think the reason behind this behaviour is your `default` value for `expirationDate`. Try passing it the `Date.now` function instead of immediately setting it to a new date:

```
expirationDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
```

This fixed it for me without having to use `markModified()`.

Comment: Changing new Date() to Date.now did not work for me. But the "workaround" did!! I have suspected that there was a datatype mismatch, which was the cause for MongoDB not updating. The forceful "markModified()" did the trick. But it still leave me the question WHY... Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: Great, happy to help. I'll maybe debug some more to find out the real reason and let you know :)

Comment: Ok, so I've tested some more and it always works for me using `Date.now`. Just to be sure - you did not use `Date.now()` (note the brackets), right? Because if you did, the field would be set to `Number` as `Date.now()` returns the number of passed ms. If you then set the value to an actual `Date` mongoose will not pick the change up, unless we use `markModified`.

Comment: Just tested again: same result, not working. After some research online, I've decided to make the datatype as String. It takes more lines of coding on the backend; but it has made the frontend display much nicer. For the moment, I just have to scratch my head and wonder why the solution works for you but not for me: database, different version of node, mongoose, or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Although we still have some unsolved issues on why the same set of codes works differently. I have decided not to deal with it for the moment. Here's my solution to the original problem: change the datatype from Date to String. Here's the new set of codes:

Creating User schema at the frontend:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    profileId: String,
    expirationDate: { type: String, default: new Date().toDateString() },
    credits: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at" } }
);
```

Updating user at the backend to MongoDB Atlas::

```
d = new Date(req.user.expirationDate);

req.user.expirationDate = new Date(
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30)
  ).toDateString();
  req.user.credits += 1;

const user = await req.user.save();

console.log(typeof req.user.expirationDate);//Checking the datatype of "expirationDate"
```